# How to use instagram search/media api search photos one month ago

Tags: api, instagram

I use INSTAGRAM media/search API to find photos from a area like [this](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=39.92&lng=116.39&max_timestamp=1372876239&client_id=XXXX&count=20&callback=XXXX)

```
max_timestamp=1372876239
```

It returns a `code 200`  but cannot get photos one month ago.

Comment: The min_timestamp and max_timestamp do not appear to be working on this endpoint right now. I've been testing and can't get any combination of them to return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the idea right, use max_timestamp to make API call, may be the location you are searching does not have photos a month ago or I have noticed that you could only go back a few days back when searching using this API. I have a implementation of this on [gramfeed](http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map?location=39.92,116.39), you can search photos at a location and select a date you want to go back to.

[image]